# as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x)) only works occasionally

Tags: r

I am currently working with a survey in a Regression Discontinuity Design.

I have seperate variables for year, month, day, hour and minute a survey was started, and I have year, month, day, hour and minute for when the survey was finished.

By `paste()` I have collapsed it into a `starttime` and an `endtime` variable, both as characters.
I then use the `as.POSIXct()` to let R know, that the characters in the variables are `datetimes`, and I use the right format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`.

Since I need the dates as numerical values, because time is the independent variable in my design, I apply following codes:

```
ESSFR$starttime_secs <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(ESSFR$starttime))

ESSFR$endtime_secs <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(ESSFR$endtime))
```

The problem is, that the code only works for `ESSFR$starttime`, and not for `ESSFR$endtime`. When applied to `ESSFR$endtime` I receive the message that

> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Do anyone know why the code only work for me occasionally?

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
    > dput(head(ESSFR[,582:591]))
structure(list(inwdds = structure(c(3, 22, 17, 21, 6, 4), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwmms = structure(c(12, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwyys = structure(c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), labels = structure(9999, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwshh = structure(c(11, 11, 16, 18, 11, 17), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwsmm = structure(c(5, 49, 21, 36, 54, 21), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwdde = structure(c(3, 22, 17, 21, 6, 4), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwmme = structure(c(12, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwyye = structure(c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), labels = structure(9999, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwehh = structure(c(12, 12, 18, 20, 13, 18), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled"), 
    inwemm = structure(c(13, 59, 5, 0, 7, 45), labels = structure(99, .Names = "Not available"), class = "labelled")), .Names = c("inwdds", 
"inwmms", "inwyys", "inwshh", "inwsmm", "inwdde", "inwmme", "inwyye", 
"inwehh", "inwemm"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is the code:

```
#Creating Dataframe only consisting of French answers
ESSFR <- ESSData %>%
  filter(cntry == "FR")

#Collapsing the seperate time variables to one.
#The time variables are: 
  #Start year = inwyys
  #Start month = inwmms
  #Start day = inwdds
  #Start hour = inwshh
  #Start minute = inwsmm

  #End year = inwyye
  #End month = inwmme
  #End day = inwdde
  #End hour = inwehh
  #End minute = inwemm

#Collapsing starttime variable
ESSFR$startdate <- paste(ESSFR$inwyys,"-",ESSFR$inwmms,"-",ESSFR$inwdds, sep = "")
ESSFR$startdate

ESSFR$startdaytime <- paste(ESSFR$inwshh,":",ESSFR$inwsmm, sep = "")
ESSFR$startdaytime

ESSFR$starttime <- paste(ESSFR$startdate,ESSFR$startdaytime)
ESSFR$starttime
class(ESSFR$starttime) #string variable generated

#Collapsing endtime variable
ESSFR$enddate <- paste(ESSFR$inwyye,"-",ESSFR$inwmme,"-",ESSFR$inwdde, sep = "")
ESSFR$enddate

ESSFR$enddaytime <- paste(ESSFR$inwehh,":",ESSFR$inwemm, sep = "")
ESSFR$enddaytime

ESSFR$endtime <- paste(ESSFR$enddate,ESSFR$enddaytime)
ESSFR$endtime
class(ESSFR$endtime) #string variable generated

#Looking at the two variables
glimpse(ESSFR$starttime)
glimpse(ESSFR$endtime)
#Looking good

#Transforming the two time varibles from string to numerical variables.
ESSFR$starttime_secs <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(ESSFR$starttime))
ESSFR$starttime_secs

ESSFR$endtime_secs <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(ESSFR$endtime))
ESSFR$endtime_secs
```

Here's a link to the data and current script
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/cb528871a341c1b2118d5db9e03d16ee20180608103455/11ca2d

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share some data to reproduce this issue

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have added a link, where the data and script can be found.

Comment: No, you need to paste the snippets of data and code into your question. Links are bad for many well-known reasons. Please edit your question.

Comment: @smci okay, I think I've done it properly now

Answer (score 1):

Likely some of your end times are NA or blank.  If they look okay when you print them, then they are probably mostly okay, but there are a few bad ones lurking in there somewhere.

You can handle the entries one at a time, giving `NA` for the bad ones, with this code.  Don't use it in production, it's very slow:

```
sapply(ESSFR$endtime_secs, 
       function(x) 
         tryCatch(as.POSIXct(x), error = function(x) NA))
```

For example,

```
ESSFR <- list(endtime_secs = c("2018-06-07 11:00 AM", "bad"))

sapply(ESSFR$endtime_secs, 
         function(x) 
           tryCatch(as.POSIXct(x), error = function(x) NA))
#> 2018-06-07 11:00 AM                 bad 
#>          1528383600                  NA
```

You can also use `strptime()` and get `NA` for bad entries, but then you need to specify the format explicitly.

Comment: As I can se, there is no missing values on the end time and the start time variable: 

`> sum(is.na(ESSFR$endtime))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(ESSFR$starttime))
[1] 0`

Comment: Then there are badly formatted entries.  What do you get after applying my `sapply` code?

Comment: Damn, now it works!! Thank you so much!